# redirected to the log in page/Color box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, colorbox

I have  a controller  that returns
System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult

I do return this.File(filename, contentType, download name);

This action is called when user is clicked on a link and
I have made  $("a[rel='popup']").colorbox();

.So whenever a user clicks on the links
 It takes to the controller method and the file
Shown in the  colour box.

Now I am facing an issue it is like 
If a user is logged in to my site and open a page 
, where links are shown and the user goes away from his seat (ie session expires)
Then he come back and clicks on the link
.At that time my application breaks as there is no valid session.

So tried to return View("LogOn");
when session is null.

But as still it is not redirected to the 
I think it is because of the colorbox

Can anyone suggest any thing such that I should be redirected to the log in page
Even if I am taking a Color box 
?

Comment: I have tried

 ctx.Response.Redirect ( "~/Home/Login" );

it goes to the curesponding login action but still it does not rendering the log in view

Answer (score 0):

When a session expires, it will not be "null", so if you're checking `if (Session == null)`, this won't work. You'll need to check for the presence of a session variable instead.

In your comment you say you're tried redirecting to /Home/Login but it doesn't render the login view. Can you elaborate? What does it render?

Comment: The view is not rendered means i am not seeing the log in page

Comment: i am just seeing the current page were i am working.The color box pop up opens and, in that pop nothing appears